# Mac Book Air mid-2012 completely disappeared disk

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, startup, sleep-wake

I've tried to wake up my Mac Book Air from sleep today, but I got a black screen.

After waiting 10 min, I decided to shut it off by holding the power button a few sec.

After restarting, I had a question mark folder flashing. So I searched and found topics like this one : [Can't boot Mac, only shows a Folder with a Question Mark?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8517/cant-boot-mac-only-shows-a-folder-with-a-question-mark)

It appears that my hard drive won't show up at all.

That is to say, if I chose the most brutal solution, i.e. reinstalling Mac OS, I can't find any disk where to install it!

It's as if my hard drive had completely disappeard!!

I've tried to boot on a linux live USB drive, but I got the same problem, it doesn't find any hard drive on my Mac Book Air.

Is there anything else I can do?

I understand my hard drive could crash badly but c'mon, I can't even find it anymore!

Comment: It is still under warranty !

Comment: Well, I have bought it on 21st of July 2012.

Comment: My math sucks, but mid 2012 and it is now mid 2013! whatever, so I assume you tried all recovery methods.

Comment: I've just checked the invoice, and it was shipped exactly one year ago.

Comment: Well rush there they will fix it :)

Comment: most probably just loose flat-band cable from SSD to motherboard.

Comment: If you do this you might VOID the warranty...http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2012+Solid-State+Drive/10961/1

Comment: I'll go to the Apple Store tomorrow mornin. I hope I won't need your link ^^

Comment: The genius guy tells me the warranty has expired 2 days ago...

Comment: Negotiate !! it is not the sending date, add 3 days for shipping so your actual warranty should start when you received it :)

Comment: Actually that was my strategy, but the genious was kind enough not to have to negociate. My McBook Air is taken care of under the warranty :)

Comment: It broke down on the last day of warranty, it just took you 2 days to get to them :) ups,...overlap :) FYI, I started communicating with you while in Munich Germany, now sitting in a 4 star hotel in Barcelona Spain that I got for $40 per night = negotiating !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left my Mac at the Apple Store, they brutally changed my SSD. I'll never know what was the problem.

However my laptop has been cleaned and I can restart installing softwares fresh as new.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive could be physically separated from the rest of the computer (i.e. the cable could have broken). This is thus not a software problem but a hardware problem. Your computer may need to be open then. You should take it in for repair.

Comment: Genius guy suggests it's a hardware problem and that the SSD is dead. I will try to make them test  the connector first.