# How to re-install an OS on Mac

Tags: mac

My friend has a Mac book pro. I'm afraid I know nothing else about it.

For reasons unknown, and I dare not ask, she decided to rub a magnet over it, beside the touch pad.

She heard a strange noise, and powered it off. Then, when turning on, she just saw a [question mark on the screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8517/cant-boot-mac-only-shows-a-folder-with-a-question-mark).

I'm guessing she's either wiped or destroyed the SSD. However, she's asked me to restore it and I know nothing about this.

Whilst my research shows me that files may have been synced to the Cloud (the cloud? Surely they mean to a server, using the technologies which have been available for years). But it doesn't state if the OS is backed up.

The computer didn't come with any discs.

On a Windows PC (which I have little experience with), I know that some times the OS isn't included but the serial number is, so you can get an ISO and re-install it that way.

Other PC's include the installation files on a partitioned hard drive.

My question is, is there a uniformed way Apple supply the OS with Mac products (unlike PC's)? If so, what is it?

Comment: simple try ...push power on and hold two keys the cmd and the letter r  that will bring up the Recovery.

Comment: That is great. I did look for things like this - a quick search shows this is a recovery partition. I'd be able to take it from there. @Buscar웃, feel free to move to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark comes up when the start up files have been messed up.

I do not know if you can repair the Magnet damage but you can try to restore.

Mac's have a Restore function build in (or online)

To access start computer and hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>

that will bring up the restore menu.

<sub>Depending on your computer model you might have the Internet restore option.</sub>

The sound you heard was the forced computer shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Restore OSX using [**OSX Recovery**](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718). To do so, hold CMD+R at the boot chime. If the recovery partition has been wiped as well, you will need to restore using **Internet Recovery**: CMD+ OPT+ R at the chime.

From either, select "Reinstall OSX" from the pane you are presented with.